# ORACLE APEX - CONOCER HISTORIAL DEL USUARIO

Tags: oracle, apex

Auditoria requiere conocer desde el Workspace conocer la fecha de creación del usuario y el historial si tuvo modificación en el registro como pasar de **LOCK** a **UNLOCK** o si hubo un cambio en este. Estuve revisando el objeto **APEX_ACTIVITY_LOG** sin éxito.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: as intentando habilitar la auditoria de la base de datos como tal?